# use RDD list as parameter for dataframe filter operation

Tags: pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have the following code snippet.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import * 

sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([                                                                           
         StructField("name", StringType(), True),
         StructField("a", StringType(), True),
         StructField("b", StringType(), True),
         StructField("c", StringType(), True),
         StructField("d", StringType(), True),
         StructField("e", StringType(), True),
         StructField("f", StringType(), True)])

arr = [("Alice", "1", "2", None, "red", None, None), \
       ("Bob", "1", None, None, None, None, "apple"), \
       ("Charlie", "2", "3", None, None, None, "orange")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(arr, schema)
df.show()

#+-------+---+----+----+----+----+------+
#|   name|  a|   b|   c|   d|   e|     f|
#+-------+---+----+----+----+----+------+
#|  Alice|  1|   2|null| red|null|  null|
#|    Bob|  1|null|null|null|null| apple|  
#|Charlie|  2|   3|null|null|null|orange|
#+-------+---+----+----+----+----+------+
```

Now, I have a RDD which is like:

```
lrdd = sc.parallelize([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']])
```

My goal is to find names which have empty subsets of attributes, that is, in the example above:

```
{'c,d,e': ['Bob', 'Charlie'], 'f': ['Alice']}
```

Now, I came to a rather naive solution that is to collect the list and then cycle through the subsets querying the dataframe.

```
def build_filter_condition(l):
    return ' AND '.join(["({} is NULL)".format(x) for x in l])

res = {}
for alist in lrdd.collect():
    cond = build_filter_condition(alist)
    p = df.select("name").where(cond)
    if p and p.count() > 0:
        res[','.join(alist)] = p.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()

print(res)
```

Which works but it's highly inefficient.
Consider also that the target attributes schema is something like 10000 attributes, leading to over 600 disjoint lists in *lrdd*.

So, my question is:
how to efficiently use the content of a distributed collection as parameter for querying a sql dataframe?
Any hint is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider the format of your data. Instead of having so many columns you should `explode` it to get more lines to allow distributed computations:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df = df.select(
    "name", 
    psf.explode(
        psf.array(
            *[psf.struct(
                psf.lit(c).alias("feature_name"), 
                df[c].alias("feature_value")
            ) for c in df.columns if c != "name"]
        )
    ).alias("feature")
).select("name", "feature.*")

    +-------+------------+-------------+
    |   name|feature_name|feature_value|
    +-------+------------+-------------+
    |  Alice|           a|            1|
    |  Alice|           b|            2|
    |  Alice|           c|         null|
    |  Alice|           d|          red|
    |  Alice|           e|         null|
    |  Alice|           f|         null|
    |    Bob|           a|            1|
    |    Bob|           b|         null|
    |    Bob|           c|         null|
    |    Bob|           d|         null|
    |    Bob|           e|         null|
    |    Bob|           f|        apple|
    |Charlie|           a|            2|
    |Charlie|           b|            3|
    |Charlie|           c|         null|
    |Charlie|           d|         null|
    |Charlie|           e|         null|
    |Charlie|           f|       orange|
    +-------+------------+-------------+
```

We'll do the same with `lrdd` but we'll change it a bit first:

```python
subsets = spark\
    .createDataFrame(lrdd.map(lambda l: [l]), ["feature_set"])\
    .withColumn("feature_name", psf.explode("feature_set"))

    +-----------+------------+
    |feature_set|feature_name|
    +-----------+------------+
    |     [a, b]|           a|
    |     [a, b]|           b|
    |  [c, d, e]|           c|
    |  [c, d, e]|           d|
    |  [c, d, e]|           e|
    |        [f]|           f|
    +-----------+------------+
```

Now we can join these on `feature_name` and filter on the `feature_set` and `name` whose `feature_value` are exclusively null. IF the lrdd table is not too big you should `broadcast` it

```python
df_join = df.join(psf.broadcast(subsets), "feature_name")
res = df_join.groupBy("feature_set", "name").agg(
    psf.count("*").alias("count"), 
    psf.sum(psf.isnull("feature_value").cast("int")).alias("nb_null")
).filter("nb_null = count")

    +-----------+-------+-----+-------+
    |feature_set|   name|count|nb_null|
    +-----------+-------+-----+-------+
    |  [c, d, e]|Charlie|    3|      3|
    |        [f]|  Alice|    1|      1|
    |  [c, d, e]|    Bob|    3|      3|
    +-----------+-------+-----+-------+
```

You can always `groupBy` `feature_set` afterwards

Comment: You made my day! I'm marking this as "accepted answer". Of course, I should avoid the `groupBy` due to the size of my input data, which lead to a driver overload. Anyway, this is definitely a sensible approach to start with. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.

First crossjoin both dataframes

```
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    lrdd = sc.parallelize([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']]).
                         map(lambda x: ("key", x))

    schema = StructType([StructField("K", StringType()),
                         StructField("X", ArrayType(StringType()))])

    df2 = spark.createDataFrame(lrdd, schema).select("X")
    df3 = df.crossJoin(df2)
```

result of crossjoin

```
    +-------+---+----+----+----+----+------+---------+
|   name|  a|   b|   c|   d|   e|     f|        X|
+-------+---+----+----+----+----+------+---------+
|  Alice|  1|   2|null| red|null|  null|   [a, b]|
|  Alice|  1|   2|null| red|null|  null|[c, d, e]|
|  Alice|  1|   2|null| red|null|  null|      [f]|
|    Bob|  1|null|null|null|null| apple|   [a, b]|
|Charlie|  2|   3|null|null|null|orange|   [a, b]|
|    Bob|  1|null|null|null|null| apple|[c, d, e]|
|    Bob|  1|null|null|null|null| apple|      [f]|
|Charlie|  2|   3|null|null|null|orange|[c, d, e]|
|Charlie|  2|   3|null|null|null|orange|      [f]|
+-------+---+----+----+----+----+------+---------+
```

Now filter out the rows using a udf

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct, collect_list 

def foo(data):

    d = list(filter(lambda x: data[x], data['X']))
    print(d)
    if len(d)>0:
        return(False)
    else:
        return(True)

udf_foo = udf(foo, BooleanType())

df4 = df3.filter(udf_foo(struct([df3[x] for x in df3.columns]))).select("name", 'X')



df4.show()
+-------+---------+
|   name|        X|
+-------+---------+
|  Alice|      [f]|
|    Bob|[c, d, e]|
|Charlie|[c, d, e]|
+-------+---------+
```

Then use groupby and collect_list to get the desired output

```
df4.groupby("X").agg(collect_list("name").alias("name")).show()
 +--------------+---------+
 |   name       |        X|
 +--------------+---------+
 | [ Alice]     |      [f]|
 |[Bob, Charlie]|[c, d, e]|
 +--------------+---------+
```

Comment: Wow. This looks amazing. I didn't think of crossJoin. Thanks. Unfortunately on the largest scenario it fails to `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeRowJoiner grows beyond 64 KB`. [More details](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16845). I'll further investigate your approach. Thanks again.